# Map Fragment crashes when entering with back button

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, inflate-exception

I have a NavigationDrawer based application. One of the fragments i load contains a GoogleMap fragment.

This is what is use to load the fragment

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, 
   new MyMapFragment()).addToBackStack("mytag1").commit();
```

The page loads without any issue and displays the map.But then when i switch to another fragment using the menu and press back button the application crashes. The fragment only contains minimal code to load the map.

**Fragment XML:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ll_report_in_out"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="my.package.name" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llv_layer2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
        >
            <!-- some content -->
        </LinearLayout>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:name="my.package.name.MyMapFragment"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity:**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_report_in_out, container, false);

        try {
            fm = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map));

            if (fm != null)
                map = fm.getMap();
            else
                map = null;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {   Log.i("dbg",e.toString()); }                         
}
```

The Catch above does not fire. The Logcat say inflate exception on line 125 which is where the fragment for the map is placed.

I would really Appreciate any help...

I am adding my current testing conditions  and work environment in case it matters

AndroidStudio 2.1
Min SDK Ver 10
Target SDK Ver 24
Compile SDK Ver 24

Testing on a Nexus 6 running Android 6.0.1

Comment: `onCreateView` method is called or not when getting back on Fragment?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K Yes onCreateView is called again when i press back button.

Answer (score 0):

Try directly using `MapView` than the `Fragment` in xml file

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:scrolling_image_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".screens.DashBoardFragment">
    <!-- Component 1 to cover half screen height -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        >

        <EditText android:id="@+id/url_live_target"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeNormal"
                android:inputType="textUri"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:hint="Receive Live Update URL" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- Component 2 to cover half screen height -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        >

        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/map_dashBoard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            />
            </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now in your Fragment

```
    private MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dash_board, container, false);

        mMapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map_dashBoard);
        mMapView.onResume();

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mGoogleMap = mMapView.getMap();

    }
```

You may need to edit logic based on your exact requirement. [Fragment adding/replacing etc]

Comment: i am unable to do that as you can tell from the layout , i need to display some content above the map.

Comment: Your code segment crashes even when i load the fragment containing the map view, with the following error   Attempt to invoke interface method 'void maps.af.y.o()' on a null object reference.

Comment: @Deepak: I Can u elaborate? "void maps.af.y.o()"

Comment: Sorry but that is exactly the error message shown in LogCat right after 'FatalException'. I even tried to put the code segment you suggested in onResume and onAttach methods. I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This solved my issue

```
View view = null;
```

In onCreateView() check this condition

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 if(view != null)
 {
   ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) container;
   if(parent !=null)
   {
     parent.removeView(view);
   }
 }
 try
 {
  view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_report_in_out, container, false);
 }
 catch(Exception e){}
 return view;
}
```

Hope this helps!